# Finding the number of missing sample points in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe.  My missing sample/data points don't take the NaN format, they've been written in as 999.99.  The full question I have is:

*Find the number of missing samples and list the date/time of each missing sample, along with the total number of missing samples.*

The code:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_table('EXAMPLE.txt', sep='\s+')

    DATE        TIME            A       B
0   2016-01-01  00:00:00.000    443.30  469.80
1   2016-01-01  00:01:00.000    145.80  470.00
2   2016-01-01  00:02:00.000    999.99  999.99
3   2016-01-01  00:03:00.000    452.20  471.00
4   2016-01-01  00:04:00.000    174.20  461.30
5   2016-01-01  00:05:00.000    745.30  471.90

print(df.loc[df['A']==999.99])

   DATE          TIME          A       B
2  2016-01-01    00:02:00.000  999.99  999.99
```

So I have in some respects got my answer, however, what I wanted to try and do is incorporate some piece of code which answers the questions, *find the number of missing samples* and *the total number of missing samples*, even though these are clearly obvious; I'm just trying for perfection here.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: What is your expected output.  In particular, any distinction between 'number of missing samples' and 'total number of missing samples'.

Comment: I'm guessing the expected output is what you got yourself.  It was a question posed to me at uni.  Like I say, my original program gave what what was needed I feel. The question seems a little silly to me.. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
missing_samples = (df[['A', 'B']] == 999.99)
missing_samples_count = missing_samples.sum().sum()
missing_samples_df = df[missing_samples.any(axis=1)]

>>> missing_samples_df
         DATE          TIME       A       B
2  2016-01-01  00:02:00.000  999.99  999.99

>>> missing_samples_count
2  # (Both 'A' and 'B')
```